# Find Haskell Int precision

Tags: function, haskell, precision

Int in Haskell uses the machines native precision. I know I can query the bounds using maxBound and minBound. Is there a similar way of querying the precision width?

Something like

```
getPrecision :: Int -> Int
```

which returns say either 32 or 64.

Comment: Try using [`sizeOf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Foreign-Storable.html#v:sizeOf) and multiply by 8?

Comment: Thanks, very simple as I suspected. Do you want to make that the answer ?

Comment: Also notice that Haskell only specifies `Int`s must be at least 29 bits.  GHC, the most common compiler, uses machine native precision.

Comment: I don't actually need 32 or 64 bits, but I do need to know exactly how many I have. I'm implementing an LFSR model, which involves shifting in new state to an existing state, and doing it efficeintly requires knowing how far to shift

Comment: @OllieB Then use a fixed width integral from `Data.Word` or `Data.Int` (ex: Word32, Int16, etc).  Don't make code work for one architecture (ex: 32-bit) and not others!

Comment: If I can get the precision of Int, I can make portable code, hence the question. My current solution is use a Int64, but I prefer more general code.

Comment: @OllieB What makes you say `Int64` is not portable?

Comment: It is, but it may not be optimal for the machine in question.

Comment: Bear in mind that the Haskell standard only guarantees 30 bits (i.e. from -(2^29) to 2^29-1 inclusive). It is true that GHC provides 32 bits on 32 bit machines and 64 bits on 64 bit machines, but you should not rely on that.

Comment: I'm aware of that. The implementation I require uses 23 bits of state, which is well within the minimum. Its a good point for others looking for reference though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way, for recent libraries (the ones that ship with GHC 7.8 or later), is to use `finiteBitSize` from `Data.Bits`. This is exactly the function you requested. With earlier versions, you can use `bitSize`, also from `Data.Bits`, a non-total version of the same thing. Specifically, `bitSize` will throw an exception if it's given something like `Integer` that doesn't have a bit size. `finiteBitSize` is in the `FiniteBits` subclass, so applying it to an `Integer` will give a type error. There's also a `bitSizeMaybe` in recent libraries, but that seems generally less useful.

Comment: If you are just asking for the size of an Int then bitSize should be fine.

Comment: @PaulJohnson, yes, but I believe it's deprecated, so I wouldn't particularly recommend it.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is

```
import Data.Bits

getPrecision = popCount (maxBound :: Int) + 1
```

Comment: That is a good solution. I'll see what else pops up, as I've seen 2 ways I've not thought of so far.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`sizeOf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Foreign-Storable.html#v:sizeOf) but this comes with the caveat that the type must not have any padding bits.

```
import Foreign (Storable, sizeOf)

getPrecision :: Storable a => a -> Int
getPrecision dummy = sizeOf dummy * 8
```